# Много столбцов в бд

Tags: проектирование, mysql

MYSQL. Есть таблица с пользователями. В ней уже 22 столбца. Хочу добавить достижения пользователей, это ещё + 5-6 столбцов. Что лучше, просто добавить эти столбцы в основную таблицу, или создать ещё одну таблицу, и при необходимости прицеплять её?

Comment: Отдельную. Таблицы, как и обычный код, должны не по максимуму собирать информацию о сущности, а собирать только конкретный аспект - базовые данные в одной таблице, достижения в другой, родственные связи в третьей, увлечения в четвертой.  
А возможно, проще будет пользоваться NoSQL-решением, где вопроса о столбцах не стоит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать отдельную таблицу для достижений с внешним ключом к таблице пользователей по полю userID (дабы нельзя было создавать достижения для несуществующего пользователя)

тогда при добавлении\изменении чего либо связанного с достижениями не придётся трогать таблицу пользователей.

Comment: ага, то есть лучше всё-таки отдельную?

Comment: ответ: тогда при добавлении\изменении чего либо связанного с достижениями не придётся трогать таблицу пользователей.